# Zepplin Proxy Code Pattern

Tags: solidity, remix, proxy-contracts

I am trying to understand the Zepplin proxy code pattern so i deployed two contracts using remix

1. `Token.sol` (logic contract - basic `ERC20` contract)
2. `AdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol` (From zepplin)

https://github.com/zeppelinos/zos/blob/master/packages/lib/contracts/upgradeability/AdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol

In the `AdminUpgradeabilityProxy` the logic/implementation address is already defined as the address to `Token.sol`.

Then I try to load the proxied contract instance by essentially loading the implementation contract (`Logic.sol`) by using the Proxy contract (`AdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol`) address.

However, in doing so any functions i call on this proxied contract fails. What is it that I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I have deployed PAXOS Standard token contracts on the Rinkeby network. (https://github.com/paxosglobal/pax-contracts/tree/master/contracts)

Implementation contract:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x075b201c705a2a49cc06c859557ccd63749ada13

Proxy Contract:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xef4360e5e6112e05618c98cbd74947d88139a19b

Comment: Can you attach any example transactions to this question? Even better, if you can run them on a public test network and link those transactions and have your contracts verified on EtherScan.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa please see the edit. Thank you

Comment: Could you verify the contracts on EtherScan, so that one gets human readable output and not just binary mess? http://etherscan.io/verifyContract2

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I have updated the contract links above ^^ and verified the code. Please have a look

Comment: Still trying to understand why but the error comes from the `require` statement in the `_willFallback()` function of the `AdminUpgradeabilityProxy` contract. I don't know if it's expected behaviour or anormal. If you want to call an admin function in the ERC20 contract through the proxy, it will always fail because of the `revert`.

Comment: @EliDrion I realized after deploying the proxy contract. I did not change the admin. That is why in the `ifAdmin()` modifier, it was not going to the `fallback()` function

Comment: I don't think you have to change the admin tho? It's set at the deployement of the contract, and even if you change it, it won't change the issue with willFallback?

Comment: Well if the admin is calling the function then it will not fallback

Answer (score 1):

The `admin` of the Proxy contract cannot call any functions on the proxied contract as they will NOT fallback. This is shown in the code excerpt of `AdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol` below:

```
modifier ifAdmin() {
   if (msg.sender == _admin()) {
       _;
    } else {
       _fallback();
    }
}
```

So the solution is to call the proxied contract by some other account e.g. the owner of the implementation contract.